# Generics and error "Cannot convert TypeX to TypeY"

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following code, I'm wanting to cast gVariable from UnsafeTypeName to SafeTypeName, although I just get an error, *Cannot convert UnsafeTypeName to SafeTypeName* on the commented line.

Although there is only one interface and class called *BetaMethods* and *ReleaseMethods*, there are actually many other 'sets', for example one is called *UntestedCharacterMethods* and *ReliableCharacterMethods*, while another set is called *UntestedVehicleMethods* and *ReliableVehicleMethods"*, although I have simply kept one set in named *BetaMethods* and *ReleaseMethods* to keep things simple for this problem. The purpose of the wrapper is to make handling these beta method and release methods a little easier.

Could somebody suggest a workaround please? (Comments added in code that provide the solution).

Thank you very much! :)

```
public interface BetaMethods {
    int GetNewCalculation();
}


public class ReleaseMethods:BetaMethods {

    public int GetNewCalculation() {
        return -1;
    }

    public int GetReliableCalculation() {
        return 0;
    }

}



public interface SafeWrapper<SafeTypeName> {
    SafeTypeName GetSafeVersion();
}


//The reason this failed as pointed out in the answers given is that UnsafeTypeName and SafeTypeName are completely unrelated. This is fixed by using the <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx">where</a> keyword.
public class UnsafeWrapper<UnsafeTypeName, SafeTypeName>:SafeWrapper<SafeTypeName> where UnsafeTypeName:SafeTypeName {

    private UnsafeTypeName gVariable;

    public SafeTypeName GetSafeVersion() {
        //Error falls on this line.
        return (SafeTypeName)gVariable;
    }

    public UnsafeTypeName GetUnsafeVersion() {
        return gVariable;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast unless you use type annotations:

```
public class UnsafeWrapper<UnsafeTypeName, SafeTypeName> 
        where UnsafeTypeName : SafeTypeName
    {

        private UnsafeTypeName gVariable;

        public SafeTypeName GetSafeVersion()
        {
            //Error falls on this line.
            return (SafeTypeName)gVariable;
        }

        public UnsafeTypeName GetUnsafeVersion()
        {
            return gVariable;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer - I've updated the question with the information you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no relation between `SafeTypeName` and `UnsafeTypeName`. In your code, they are both unrelated types.

If you want to force inheritance between the two, you can use generic constraint ([where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)).

To be more specific, it could work if you cange it like this:

```
public class UnsafeWrapper<UnsafeTypeName, SafeTypeName>:SafeWrapper<SafeTypeName> where SafeTypeName : UnsafeTypeName
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer - I've updated the question with the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Type casting works within Inheritance heirarchy. If the types are unrelated, the casting won't work.